# Laravel 10 - Running a factory - ParseErrorException.php

Tags: laravel, parsing, factory

I have this factory I am trying to run through Tinker:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\User;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\User>
 */
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $model = User::class;
    
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'active' => true,
            'name' => fake()->name,
            'role_id' =>  (int)fake()->randomElement([1,2]),
            'email' => fake()->freeEmailDomain()->unique(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi',
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

I did `composer update` beforehand:

[image: 'composer update' result]

The error I am getting:

[image: Tinker error message]

- I tried using different syntaxes in `UserFactory.php` for faker. (For faker, I am using the syntax used in Laravel 10 official documentation)
- I am not too clear about the error message.
- I have run factories on this machine before with a slightly different syntax but I am not familiar with this PHP Parse error.
- I can't check any Laravel logs yet because I am trying first to have the DB tables filled with a few rows.

Thanks for the help

Comment: delete the `vendor` and the `composer.lock`, and then do the `composer install`, check if you have again a problem on the vendor again.

Comment: try $this->faker instead of fake() function

Comment: Try commenting out the factory fields one by one to find the culprit. Also, try returning an empty array in your factory to see if you have this error.

Comment: @Nehal -  that does not solve the issue.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa - commenting out the factory fields one by one and returning an empty array does not solve the issue.

Comment: First try inverting `fake()->freeEmailDomain()->unique()` to `fake()->unique()->freeEmailDomain()`, if that does not work, try running `php artisan tinker -vvv` and see if when you run the factory again, it prints out a longer error, so you can track which exact line of the factory is being executed and ends up in the error on that vendor folder. Finally, also try running your code adding `;` at the end of `create()`, as you did not close the line...

Comment: @francisco -  I deleted the vendor folder and the composer.lock file, ran 'composer install' in my terminal (all packages were found) , same error message.

Comment: @matiaslauriti - No  ';' is required when running a tinker command. Inverting freeDomain() and unique() did not change anything. When I run php artisan tinker - vvv,  it shows me the same error message and a list of Psy classes, Illuminate classes , Symfony component classes.  The process stops at Kernel->handle() at artisan:35 [link]https://ibb.co/HCnsK9K

Comment: Run `User::factory()->count(20)->create();` from any of your Controller methods so that you get a proper full error stack trace in `storage\logs\laravel.log`

Comment: The error you are getting is very very weird... I would run the factory from inside laravel as @steven7mwesigwa said so you have a better log and we can debug way better

Comment: @KamiBarut can you show us what you have done on your route to trigger the factory? Do you have `APP_DEBUG=true`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti - APP_DEBUG is set to true in my .env file. The answer to your first question is on this screenshot : [link] https://ibb.co/0tzmqbh

Comment: @matiaslauriti - SOLVED. This was the issue 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-8-error-target-class-homecontroller-does-not-exist -- Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Run as follows

```
Database\Factories\UserFactory::new()->count(10)->create();
```

Comment: @steven7mwesiga - Nothing shows up in storage\logs\laravel.log even though I created a route and entered User::factory()->count(20)->create() in the controller and method associated with that route.

Comment: to Sina Nbxh : using Database\Factories\UserFactory::new()->count(10)->create(); --> nothing shows up in the log file nor in the database.